# How to remove an element from an array in react js

Tags: reactjs

On button click below function is executed. On another click of the button i want to remove the element from the array.

```
    const { occasions: selectedOccasions } = formData
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      occasions: selectedOccasions.includes({ occasion })
        ? selectedOccasions.filter({ occasion })
        : [...selectedOccasions, occasion],
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`includes()` function works with array. its a array funtion. `[].includes("text")`
and you cant give a object to paramter of `includes()`. also filter is a function that working with array. You can't give object. You should check javascript array methods.

includes => https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

filter => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: My code is working fine with adding occasions on the array. My question is how to modify the above code to pop an element from the array